# Instagram API - How to build a media viewer to get posts by hashtag from some users?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible? I have read the documentation but I wish to know there is one way. I need to create a gallery with some hashtags and filter by some users. Maybe something in the backend can do it?

Answer (score 1):

No. From the official api, you can't get other users' media anymore. They only allow developers or users to fetch their own "RECENT" media. So does hashtags.
More and more restrictions and fewer and fewer APIs opened by Instagram, it's hard to do valuable stuff around IG now.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. The developer client key defaults to your own content in sandbox mode. You have to create a submission for approval, you can do this via: https://www.instagram.com/developer/clients/ and choose the client that you have created, then the permissions tab will allow you to apply.

I am going through the application process at the moment for our App, it is very difficult as Instagram are stringent.